# Apps Script to render background color based on name in cell for all tabs in a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to automate color into the background of Column A across all tabs of my spreadsheet based on the color name entered into each cell. I will associate the additional Hex codes as the color list grows. Please le me know what I am doing wrong. It seems my function doesn't exist? I am very new to this stuff so just swimming in the deep end of the JS world and a little lost. Thanks for any info.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXZ4z.png)

I tried a function I found but do not know how to customize for my use case. Unsure if the spacing or Variables line up as the past didn't work great.

---

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  // Define the color mapping. You can add more color mappings as needed.
  var colorMap = {
    "Acorn": "#5b0f00",
    "Avacado": "#38761d",
    "Blossom": "#f78484"
    // Add more colors and their corresponding hex codes here
  };

  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the names of all sheets in the spreadsheet
  var sheetNames = spreadsheet.getSheetNames();

  // Loop through each sheet
  sheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Get the data range in Column A
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());

    // Get the values in Column A
    var values = range.getValues();

    // Loop through each cell in Column A
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var cellValue = values[i][0].trim(); // Trim any leading/trailing spaces
      var cellBackgroundColor = colorMap[cellValue];

      if (cellBackgroundColor) {
        // Set the background color of the cell
        range.getCell(i + 1, 1).setBackground(cellBackgroundColor);
      }
    }
  });
 }
```

---

Comment: There is no method for a spreadsheet named getSheetNames()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var colorMap = { "Acorn": "#5b0f00", "Avacado": "#38761d", "Blossom": "#f78484" };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shtnames = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());//this gets sheet names
  shtnames.forEach(function (name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
    var vs = range.getDisplayValues().flat();
    vs.forEach((e,i) => {
      let cv = vs[i].trim();
      let bg = colorMap[cv];
      if(bg) {
        range.getCell(i+1,1).setBackground(bg)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper that was the solution. Really appreciate the help with this one.